# Scalar-on-function regression with random initial time

Tags: regression, time-series, multilevel-analysis, time-varying-covariate, functional-data-analysis

I was trying to answer this question

[Estimating the effect of different histories of exposure, on a scalar response measured at the end of a study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292579/estimating-the-effect-of-different-histories-of-exposure-on-a-scalar-response-m)

Executive summary if you don't want to read the original thread: OP has data for a cohort of $\sim 20000$ subjects. For each subject we have a vector of covariates $\mathbf{x}_i$ (age, smoking habit, social class, etc.), the time history $\mathcal{X}_i(t) \colon [t_i, T]\to\mathbb{R}$ of exposure to a certain environmental variable, and a blood pressure $y$ measurement t the end of the study (time $T$). Blood pressure at time $t_i$ (i.e., when recording of exposure started for subject $i$) wasn't measured, unfortunately.

OP wants to estimate the effect of $\mathcal{X}_i(.)$ on $y$, when controlling for $\mathbf{x}_i$. I proposed to use a linear [scalar-on-function regression model](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/insr.12163/full) (see also [here](https://works.bepress.com/phil_reiss/40/download/) for a freely downloadable copy):

$$y_i=\alpha_0+\boldsymbol{\alpha}^T\mathbf{x}_i+\int_0^T\beta(s)\mathcal{X}_i(s)\text{d}s+\epsilon_i, \qquad i=1,\dots,N$$

Some explanations are in order here:

- $\alpha_0$  is the intercept, and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is the vector
  of coefficients for the scalar covariates $\mathbf{x}_i$
- $\beta(t)$ is called a coefficient function, and like $\alpha_0$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, it must be estimated
- finally, $\epsilon_i$ are iid, mean 0, constant variance errors, usually assumed to be normally distributed

The issue here is that actually this model assumes that all time series start at at the same time. Instead, here measurements of the exposure variables started at different times for different subjects. I can see two ways out of this:

1. One can make all time series start at the same time, maybe $t_{min}=\min\limits_{i=1,\dots,N} t_i$, and treat the missing measurements as missing data. I don't know if this is feasible and if it has ever been done before for scalar-on-function regression. I'm not thrilled by this approach, because obviously data won't be missing at random (for each subject, all measurements $t\mid t_{min}<t<t_i$ will be missing, not just some data at random).
2. Another possibility: a multilevel model where we give some prior on
   $t_i$ (maybe derived by looking at the data, which would make this
   an Empirical Bayes approach), and then, conditional on $t_i$, we
   model $y_i|t_i$ as

   $$y_i|t_i=\alpha_0+\boldsymbol{\alpha}^T\mathbf{x}_i+\int_{t_i}^T\beta(s)\mathcal{X}_i(s)\text{d}s+\epsilon_i,
   \qquad i=1,\dots,N$$

   Does it makes sense? How could one fit such a model?

I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: your functional linear regression model seems fine for me. your additional problem with the irregular design points (assuming all points are theoretically in a common intervall) may also be known as sparseness in this context. You may want to take a look at "Functional Data Analysis for Sparse
Longitudinal Data" by Yao, Müller and Wang.

Comment: @chRrr thanks for the pointer to the paper - it's massive! I'll try to read it this week. I'm not sure that this simply a sparse data problem though - it's not only that the time series are irregularly sampled, it's also that they have widely different durations. If you have a look at the [plot on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4AZt.jpg), you can clearly see that, for some subjects, the length of the time series is just one third (or less) of the length for other subjects.